# Accessing OPC data with Java

Tags: java, opc, scada

I am totally new to OPC, I was given a Visual Basic Script that accesses data from an OPC server,

The only thing I know about the OPC server is that is compatible with SCADA OPC Data Access 1.0a y 2.05. I just have the Visual Basic code, and need to port it to Java.

I am not asking for a complete solution, I just need a few guidelines, I have found a couple APIs (Like Utgard and JEasyOPC) but I am not sure if this will work, as I have no idea what `compatible with SCADA OPC Data Access 1.0a y 2.05` means, and found no references to it.

Does someone have experience with this? Can you guys give me a few guidelines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPC Data Access is one of the COM-based OPC interfaces, others being e.g OPC Alarm & Events and OPC Historical Data Access. 1.0a and 2.05 are versions of the OPC Data Access specification, and the OPC server you want to extract data from complies with both versions.

I have never worked with Utgard, but based on the available documentation, it is compliant with version 2.05. So, Utgard should work with that OPC server.

Answer (score 0):

We work with the openscada utgard library for out system. The library itself works very good, but it is relying on the jinterop library which has it's quirks.

Comment: Most of the "quirks" are usually in DCOM itself, which was never meant to play nicely with anything else.